# Tapping on Map Marker results in AlertDialog displaying all other Map Markers

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a description column in my SQLite database that contains some text to display when taping to every marker. Every marker has its own description. The problem is when I tap on one marker, I'm getting all of the other `AlertDialog`s displayed. I'm using the following code:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

     String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};
     Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
     cur.moveToFirst();
     while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
          String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
          dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
          dialog.setMessage(description);
          dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
           dialog.show();

           cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();

    return true;
}
```

The `onTap` function seems to be working:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

     String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};
     Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

     cur.moveToPosition(index);
     String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));

     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
     dialog.setTitle("Infos.");
     dialog.setMessage(description);
     dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {    
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
          }
     });
     dialog.show();
     cur.close();

     db.close();

             return true;
        }
```

I am aware that I have to assign an index to every `AlertDialog`, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried to solve this but I can't seem to do it. Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looping through all the items in your results.

**cur.moveToFirst()** moves you to the first item, then **cur.moveToNext();** moves you to the next item on each iteration. You are then displaying the alert dialog for every item!

You really shouldn't need to load the data like this every time the user clicks on an item, but the simplest [not recommended] way to fix your code would be to use **cur.moveToPosition(index)** instead of your loop.

Comment: Exactly. You mean so that i have to replace `cur.moveToFirst()` with `cur.moveToPosition(index)` and delete `cur.moveToNext()` ? And why it's not recommended ?

Comment: Not recommended, because you should only load your data once - when you bind it to the view. You haven't posted this code so it's difficult to comment. You should load it into a local collection. Then, when the user taps on an item, simply access the correct item by its index.

Comment: I tried `cur.moveToPosition(index)`, the application freezes then Force closes.

Comment: You didn't post the new code, but I can only guess you just removed that line rather than trying to understand what is happening. And you are therefore in an infinite loop. Get rid of your while loop. Have you thought about what would happen if an item is deleted in between when you display the data and click on an item?

Comment: Yes, you have reason, it's working at 90%. I'm just having a FC with a marker of index 4: `08-23 16:40:08.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6742): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
` The compiler have to request index 3 for this marker? What's the source of that FC in your opinion ?